# Can I use py2app or py2exe to make my python code as an exe/DMG to works on all windows or macs

Tags: python, py2exe, py2app

My question is if for example if I build my python code using py2app and then transfer the Dist folder to another mac will it works on all mac os, and the same question for py2exe , will it works on all windows pc ? If this is not possible , then is there any other way for it to works?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, but this macOS app you created will be denied opening on another Mac because it doesn't work. the application has an unidentified developer.On windows problems with access not happed.